# How to run Julia project from GitHub in VS Code?

Tags: github, julia

Could someone please tell me how one could run a project downloaded from github written in Julia in VS Code? I tried Executing the .jl files in REPL by right clicking on the file and clicking on "Execute File in REPL"  but nothing.

I also tried "Activating the Environment" of the src file, and still nothing.

Any and all help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: would you be able to share the GitHub project? it really depends on how the project is structured

Answer (score 0):

1. You open the file you wish to run (you must know which one it is)
2. In the start menu you select "Run -> Run Without Debugging" or press "Ctrl+F5"

[image]